# How to execute multi-line Maxima code from Octave / Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, maxima

I can execute Maxima code from Octave like this and it works:

```
mm=maxima("diff(a*x^3-b*x^2+x+d,x,1)")
```

but how can I execute multi line commands?

**Example code below that works in Maxima**

```
kill(all)$
numer:true$
ratprint:false$
angle_in_bits:3779$
total_fs:18136$
s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg)$
round(s); 
[round(angle_deg)=75]
```

When I try the code below in Octave I get syntax errors

```
mm=maxima("kill(all)$
numer:true$
ratprint:false$
angle_in_bits:3779$
total_fs:18136$
s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg)$
round(s);")
```

Errors that I get:

```
>>> mm=maxima("kill(all)$
numer:true$
ratprint:false$
angle_in_bits:3779$
total_fs:18136$
s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg)$
round(s);")
error: unterminated character string constant
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> mm=maxima("kill(all)$
                        ^

>>> _ide_reload_variables_list( whos() );
error: 'numer' undefined near line 1 column 1
error: invalid base value in colon expression
error: 'ratprint' undefined near line 1 column 1
error: invalid base value in colon expression
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> angle_in_bits:3779$
                      ^

parse error:

  syntax error

>>> total_fs:18136$
                  ^

parse error:

  syntax error

>>> s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg)$
                                                             ^

error: unterminated character string constant
parse error:

  syntax error

>>> round(s);")
              ^
```

Comment: I don't have octave, but in Maxima you can make multiple statements into a single one by enclosing the whole lot in parentheses and separating them with commas, e. g. `(kill(all), numer:true, ratprint:false,
angle_in_bits:3779, total_fs:18136, s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg), round(s))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Fred Senese and rayryeng for the assist.

I know someone may need this so here's some example code.  This bit of code allows you to directly access maxima's symbolic solver from octave (allows you to execute multiple lines of maxima's commands).  Since octave doesn't have a good symbolic solver yet this will come in handy for another person down the line.

```
mm=maxima("(kill(all), numer:true, ratprint:false, angle_in_bits:3779, total_fs:18136, s:solve(angle_deg=(angle_in_bits/total_fs*360),angle_deg),(s))")
%mm = '[angle_deg = 75.01323334803705]';

[si ei xt mt] = regexp(mm, '(\d)*(\.)?(\d)*');
number = str2num(mt{1})

>>>number =  75.013
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suppose here that you are using QtOctave which I am guessing from googling your error message "_ide_reload_variables_list( whos() );"
If this is not so, none of the following may apply to your question.

typing `help maxima` at the prompt points me to a file /usr/share/qtoctave/scripts_octave/maxima.m 
with this contents:

```
function result=maxima(command)
in="";
in=sprintf("echo \"string(%s);\"|maxima --very-quiet", command);
[status,result]=system(in);
%if(status!=0) result=""; endif;
result = deblank ( strjust (   strrep (result, "%", "")  ,"left") ); 
endfunction
```

Which tells me that maxima is called via octave's function `system` in a very special way that is not allowing for multiple commands in maxima.

modifying the assignment of `in` in the way below would allow you to call the function `maxima` now with a cell array of commands `maxima({command_1,command_2})` where `command_i` are strings.

`in=['echo ', sprintf('\"%s;\" ',command{:}), '| maxima --very-quiet'];`

Please note that the function `system` still returns only *one* output, the one that is sent to standard out by maxima.

[This](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Controlling-Subprocesses.html) may also be of interest for you as it describes methods of octave's interaction with subprocesses.

I am not sure if this helping much as I think the modification provided by me is only of very superficial use, but maybe it helps you to understand better what octave is doing if you tell it `maxima(something)`. It helped me.

Last but not least as far as I know there is no *real* interface between octave (or matlab) and maxima. I hope someone will correct me if I am wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have Octave and Maxima in my Linux laptop (Ubuntu). There exist system -function in Octave, which could be used to run terminal -commands.

In terminal it is possible to call maxima functions by using pipe
(add quit(); to the end of maxima command) :

$ echo "factor(12345); quit();" | maxima

Maxima 5.41.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
(%i1) (%o1)                               3 5 823
$

In Octave' system -commad use double "" inside "-marks to get " :

> > [status,output]=system("echo ""factor(565);quit();""|maxima")
> > status = 0
> > output =
> > Maxima 5.41.0 http://maxima.sourceforge.net
> > using Lisp GNU Common Lisp (GCL) GCL 2.6.12
> > Distributed under the GNU Public License. See the file COPYING.
> > Dedicated to the memory of William Schelter.
> > The function bug_report() provides bug reporting information.
> > (%i1) (%o1)                                5 113

Extra txt could be cutted out from the output -string in Octave. Use Maxima's properties to run it's commands from a script file, and the script could be created in Octave.

Br. Juha  (juhap.karjalainen@mail.suomi.net)